# Dynamically adding a text inside the LinearLayout

Tags: android

I need help to place text at text1 and text2 dynamically and these both text's should not exceed the border of the image.

For eg:

```
   " Welcome " will be fixed at text2, but in case of "Welcome to the World of Android" may not be ,how could i fix it within the space provided.
```

My image will be exactly looks like this and placed at the center of the layout.
How could i place the text in the respective places which should be compatible with all type of devices[Tab & HandSet] and in all kind of resolutions.

I have tried it by creating separate linear layouts dynamically with fixed margins and placed these text's for each branches, but the problem is it's not fine with all kind of devices.

Here is my image :

[image]

Here s the layout with more explanation

[image]

All these are one whole image which holds one parent Linearlayout and the branches(linear1) only holds the text part with dynamic linearlayouts, as i said the text1 and text2 has to be fixed within the section provided.

Please post your suggestions.

Comment: Paste your xml code for layout.

Comment: <LinearLayout 
             android:id="@+id/goalsParent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/image">
                
            </LinearLayout>

Comment: I want the text's should be added dynamically, 'coz layout holds the whole image. so its not possible to add the text through Xml. Above have posted my xml for the layout.

Answer (score 0):

you just read Gravity and Padding property your problem solve

Comment: Have already given those things but nothing works.My actual problem resides at the margin fix.

Answer (score 0):

circle is png file in which circle draw ::

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
```

Comment: K fine, if the width is WrapContent in case of a lengthy text it 'll exceed the limits and the image seems to be stretched ,thats y i have fixed the dynamic linearlayout params as like this              LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((widthContentView/2)/3)- 15, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); llParams.setMargins(10, 75, 20, 0);     But it's not fine with all devices . I want this to be fine on all also with the orientation too.

Comment: The left side oval holds one separate layout(dynamic) and the right one has different. Also it has to be created programatically not  by xml.  If u have any suggestions please post it.